# How to automate js files join for prod deploy in play framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, automation, playframework-1.x

I'm working on a project where the front end uses AngularJs (it is a SPA) and the backend uses Play Framework 1.3. Our angularJs file is growing up fast so it would be nice to split it and use some kind of directory structure to keep organized all of the directives, controllers, filters, etc in diferent files. But I only want this in dev enviroment.

When we deploy to a production server we want to find an automated solution to 'join' all the js files into a single minified version.

So for example in production the index.html should look like this:

```
<script src="some/dir/myAngularCode.min.js"></script>
```

and in dev environment I want it to look like this:

```
<script src="/some/dir/controllers/controller-1.js"></script>
<script src="/some/dir/controllers/controller-2.js"></script>
<script src="/some/dir/directives/directive-1.js"></script>
<script src="/some/dir/directives/directive-2.js"></script>
```

and so on...

Could you guide me to do this? I couldn't find anything related to Play Framework,thereare lots of examples with nodejs but we are not using node here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just install node for the build process? What's the harm?

Comment: well that's a good point, didn't think about it. I never used node so i'm not familiar with the build process. If I do what you say it would be necessary to install node in our Heroku production environment right?

Comment: Not usually. Normally you do all your bundling locally before you push to production, but that's up to you. Install Node and look at gulp. It's pretty straightforward https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp

Comment: We're doing same operation with gulp.js. 

Also in heroku you can add node [buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks).

Then in your `Procfile`;

`web:  node node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js  && play run --http.port=$PORT $PLAY_OPTS ` 

It's done.

Comment: I finally ended up using npm and uglifyjs for this task. Was pretty easy and straight forward.